# Enable sharding mongocxx

Tags: c++, mongodb, sharding, mongo-cxx-driver

I wonder how to execute these command by using mongocxx 3.1.3 (Mongo C++ driver):

```
sh.enableSharding("YourDB")
sh.shardCollection("YourDB.YourCollection", {field:hashed})
```

I've searched for 3 hours and still not find out the way. Any idea?

Comment: Curious. Why are you trying to do administrative job via driver? Can't you just enable sharding via shell and  consume it with choice of language.

Comment: I agree with this comment, as I'd normally expect administrative operations to be done via the shell, but it certainly could make sense in some sort of testing scenario to enable it programmatically.

Comment: @Saleem I know it can be done via shell, but like acm said, for testing purpose, I really need to enable it by code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver doesn't offer helpers for this, but you can invoke the command on the server by using [`mongocxx::database::run_command`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-v3/classmongocxx_1_1database.html#a1ce8581871d060bce35739a682fc35e9) with arguments as specified in the manual for the [enableSharding command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/enableSharding/).